# How can I change consensus algorithm in Hyperledger sawtooth-supply-chain api (FishNet example)?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to change my consensus algorithm in the FishNet example.

In `/sawtooth-supply-chain-master/fish_client/public/dist/bundle.js` file I found this:

`consensus":{"type":"bytes","id":5}`

Does anybody knows what is the mapping of consenus ids in sawtooth?

By default it is Devmode. But I want to change the consensus type. Is this possible ?

And in /sawtooth-supply-chain-master/docker/compose/supply-chain-default.yaml

entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        if [ ! -f /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen &&
          sawtooth keygen my_key &&
          sawset genesis -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv &&
          sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch
        fi;
        sawtooth-validator -v \
          --endpoint tcp://validator:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050
      "

devmode-engine:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust-default
    depends_on:
      - validator
    entrypoint: devmode-engine-rust -C tcp://validator:5050

Answer (score 1):

### Sawtooth Dynamic Consensus Overview

Hyperledger Sawtooth supports a [dynamic consensus model](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/about_dynamic_consensus.html#about-dynamic-consensus). As you mentioned, the default consensus engine is `Devmode`.

Other supported consensus engines include:

- [PBFT](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/about_dynamic_consensus.html#pbft-consensus)
- [PoET](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/about_dynamic_consensus.html#poet-consensus)
- [Raft](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/about_dynamic_consensus.html#raft-consensus)

The consensus type is an on-chain setting. From the documentation:

```
Each consensus type has a consensus engine that communicates 
with the validator through the consensus API. Each node in 
the network must run the same consensus engine.
```

### Configuring The Network

To use a consensus type other than the default `Devmode`, you will need to update two on-chain settings:

- `sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name`
- `sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version`

This must be done through a [sawset proposal create](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0.0rc1/cli/sawset.html#sawset-proposal) command, which can be done while the network is running, or included in a batch as part of the genesis block, e.g.:

```
sawadm keygen && \
  sawtooth keygen my_key && \
  sawset genesis -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv && \
  sawset proposal create \
    -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv \
    sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name= pbft \
    sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=1.0 \
    sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=["VAL1KEY","VAL2KEY",...,"VALnKEY"] \
    -o config.batch \
  && sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch
```

Note that `config.batch` (which contains our proposal to update the consensus mode) needs to be included in `sawadm genesis`.

I would suggest looking at the documentation on [Setting Up a Sawtooth Network](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/setting_up_sawtooth_network.html) for more info - particularly step 4 of [Creating the Genesis Block](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/creating_genesis_block.html).